# Git fatal error on trying to clone directly from Ansible

Tags: git, github, deployment, ansible, clone

I'm using ansible (Trellis) to deploy my projects.

I have a repo on github.

This is my ansible code

```yaml
- name: UPDATE - Clone project files
  become: yes
  # become_user: "{{ project.user.name | default(ansible_web_user) }}"
  git:
    repo: "{{ project.git.ssh }}"
    dest: "{{ project_root }}/shared/source"
    version: "{{ project.git.branch | default('master') }}"
    accept_hostkey: "{{ project.git.accept_hostkey | default(repo_accept_hostkey | default(true)) }}"
    force: yes
    # key_file: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
  ignore_errors: false
  no_log: false
  register: git_clone
```

For some days this error has appeared for no apparent reason, nothing has changed

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master", "msg": "fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stderr_lines": ["fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository", "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.", "", "Please make sure you have the correct access rights", "and the repository exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

I've tried several solutions, even removing the `forwardAgent` and forcing the `key_file` directly into the git call. It still returns an error.

But if I connect via ssh to the target machine and try to do a `git clone ....` everything works.

I don't understand what the problem could be.

Comment: `I don't understand what the problem could be` <= I don't know how the GitHub error message can be clearer. There are only 2 possible root cause to your issue: either `{{ project.git.ssh }}` points to a repo which does not exist or you don't have the correct permissions to access that repository (i.e. no permission for the given user or using the wrong ssh key). If you are trying to force the key you want to use, the reference should be your private key, not the public one.

Comment: I also tried creating a new ssh key on server (id_rsa_new) and adding it as deploy
keys of the repo, but nothing to do the error persists.

I'm sure the repo and keys exist. If I try with a git clone directly on the machine everything works. Only via ansible do I have this problem.

Comment: So what happens if you `cd "{{ project_root }}/shared/source" && git remote -v` to see what it thinks the _current_ `origin` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
- name: UPDATE - Safe Directory
  command: git config --global --add safe.directory {{ project_root }}/shared/source
  check_mode: no
```

and editing

```
- name: UPDATE - Clone project files
  # become: yes
  # become_user: "{{ project.user.name | default(ansible_web_user) }}"
  git:
    repo: "{{ project.git.ssh }}"
    dest: "{{ project_root }}/shared/source"
    version: "{{ project.git.branch | default('master') }}"
    accept_hostkey: "{{ project.git.accept_hostkey | default(repo_accept_hostkey | default(true)) }}"
    force: yes
    key_file: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
    update: no
  ignore_errors: false
  no_log: false
  register: git_clone
```

I solve the problem ;)

Comment: FYI: `git config ... --add` appends redundant lines to your ~/.gitconfig on every execution. See my post below for an idempotent syntax.

Answer (score 3):

### Summary

I also ran into this a few months ago:

- **Use case**: application being deployed using Ansible and git, with an invocation like:

  ```
    - name: "Git clone"
      git:
        repo: "ssh://git@github.com/somewhere/something.git"
        accept_hostkey: yes
        key_file: "/foo/bar/{{ deployment_name }}/.ssh/id_rsa"
        dest: "/foo/bar/{{ deployment_name }}/foofoo/barbar"
        version: "{{ my_version }}"
  ```
- **Symptoms**:

  - An Ansible deployment running git suddenly stopped working (after an apt-get upgrade)
  - Running git manually in the same clone works normally, problem only appears under Ansible

The **root cause seems to be that Ansible is running git as root** (or `become_user`), while the git clone on disk is (on purpose) owned by someone else.

Also, the message *"'origin' does not appear to be a git repository"* from git is misleading.

### Debugging

I had to resort to desperate measures to uncover this, though, namely replacing `/usr/bin/git` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /tmp/git-db < /dev/null || exit 1
env        < /dev/null > /tmp/git-db/git.$$.env   2> /tmp/git-db/err
echo "$@"  < /dev/null > /tmp/git-db//git.$$.args 2> /tmp/git-db/err
pwd        < /dev/null > /tmp/git-db//git.$$.pwd  2> /tmp/git-db/err
id         < /dev/null > /tmp/git-db//git.$$.id   2> /tmp/git-db/err
#sleep 3600  < /dev/null                            2> /tmp/git-db/err
exec /usr/bin/git.real "$@"
```

Looking at the `/tmp/git-db/git.*.id` files (and `ps` with the sleep enabled) showed that ansible was running /usr/bin/git as root. Testing git as root on the gave a clue to the workaround OP already posted:

```
root@foo-app01:/data/www/foo/foobar# git status
fatal: unsafe repository ('/data/www/foo/foobar' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory /data/www/foo/foobar
```

Reproducing the git invocation that Ansible actually chokes on produced the same broken error message we've seen:

```
root@foo-app01:/data/www/foo/foobar# GIT_SSH_OPTS=-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no GIT_KEY=/data/www/foo/.ssh/id_rsa /usr/bin/git.real ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

### Workaround

As OP already mentioned, whitelisting the directory in the target machine's git configuration works around the issue:

(EDIT: replaced "--add" with idempotent syntax. Using --add appends redundant lines to your /root/.gitconfig on every execution (see `git-config(1)`).

```
- name: "Patch /root/.gitconfig"
  # This invocation (without --add, with the dir name twice) is idempotent
  command: |-
    git config --global safe.directory /data/www/{{ foo }}/{{ bar}} /data/www/{{ foo }}/{{ bar}}
```

### What should work, but doesn't

A more appropriate fix would be to execute git as the user that owns the git clone directory. This should be possible with `become_user`, but adding the incantations to the invocation has no effect. With ...

```
- name: "Git clone"
  become_user: foobar
  become: true
  git:
    repo: "ssh://git@github.com/somewhere/something.git"
    accept_hostkey: yes
    key_file: "/foo/bar/{{ deployment_name }}/.ssh/id_rsa"
    dest: "/foo/bar/{{ deployment_name }}/foofoo/barbar"
    version: "{{ my_version }}"
```

... ansible is *still* executing `/usr/bin/git` as root, evidenced by the wrapper above. This happens on ansible 2.9 and 6.2.0 (installed using pip).

Comment: This seems to be caused when not using an inventory file and thus the direct local connection. 
I couldn't find your bug report, so I reported it here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/80233

Comment: In my case (described above) it was happening when using an inventory, i.e. a regular "ansible-playbook -i inventory/ -D -C deploy.yml" invocation.

I didn't file one a bug report, but thanks for mentioning it here.

Comment: For me, `become_user: foobar` +  `become: true` worked using ansible 2.13.8. If it has been fixed in ansible.builtin.git, I think this should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # key_file: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
> ```

Note, the [`key_file` attribute of the `git` Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#parameter-key_file) is supposed to reference a private key, not the public one.

But check first the value of `{{ project.git.ssh }}`, to make sure it is a valid GitHub SSH URL like `git@github.com:me/myRepo`. If not, or if empty, that would explain the `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository` error message.